# Sum of the terms of a AP

Tags: python

I wrote a code to display the numbers of a AP, linked with the condition of a inputted number

```
P = int(input())
R = int(input())
Q = int(input())
S = 0
Cont = 0
while Cont<=Q:
 print("Termo",Cont,"da PA = ",P)
 P = P+R
 Cont = Cont+1
```

It worked fine, but in this case, how can I sum all the terms of the AP ?

Comment: What do you mean by AP? And what are the terms of an AP?

Comment: `print("Termo",Cont,"da PA = ",P, "sum =", P+Cont*R)`

Assuming you are talking about arithmetic progressions.

Answer (score 0):

Add the calculated terms in the loop.

```
P = int(input())
R = int(input())
Q = int(input())
S = 0
Cont = 0
while Cont<=Q:
 print("Termo",Cont,"da PA = ",P)
 S = S + P
 P = P+R
 Cont = Cont+1

print("Sum:",S)
```

Comment: In this case it shows the wrong sum, for example: if the value for P , R and Q are respective 1, 1 and 10 the correct sum of terms till Cont <=Q will be 65, if I use the code it will show "Sum: 78"